# SQL script than create table and and fill it out file Resources.resx

Tags: sql, sql-server, resx, sql-scripts

I need to write a sql script that will create a table in the database and populate it with data from the file type Resources.resx

As far as I can see, there are only 3 fields: Name, Value and Comment. All string.

I using Microsoft SQL  Server (Management Studio)

```
<data name="Filter" xml:space="preserve">
<value>Фильтры</value></data>
```

Comment: This is a statement, not a question. Please tell us your actual problem.

Comment: I need import this data (Resources.resx) in table in Microsoft Sql  Server, using sql scripts. Sorry by low English) Thanks=)

Comment: Please provide data from `Resources.resx`

Comment: `Resources.resx` contains only this rows?

Comment: yes, data of Resources.resx (no header) contains only this rows

Comment: @Dmitry Tetchenko, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '
<data name="Filter" xml:space="preserve">
     <value>Фильтры</value>
</data>'

CREATE TABLE dbo.translations
(
      name VARCHAR(100)
    , value NVARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.translations (name, value)
SELECT 
       name = t.c.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(100)')
     , value = t.c.value('./value[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)')
FROM @XML.nodes('data') t(c)

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.translations
```

Output -

```
name       value
---------- ----------
Filter     Фильтры
```

Comment: Thanks:)  But how I can copy table from result of query to my table or create new table in database with this data?

Comment: Just specify in which table you want insert data for the file. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: An new empty table "translations" with 2 cols (name and value (varchar))